# How to get file path of image which is selected from pc in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

i am trying to get file path of images which are selected from pc using input tag. i am using this

```
  <input type="file" ng-model="imagesrc" accept="image/*">
```

but i am unable to file path of image. please help me.

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: i am new to angularjs so i don't have idea how to get path so i am asking for help

Answer (score 0):

`ngModel` does not apply to input of type `file` (see [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) on AngularJS site).
You will have to write your own directive, or use an existing one like this [ngFileModel](https://github.com/mistralworks/ng-file-model)

You will also not have the path of the file, only the filename, due to security restrictions, JS does not have full access to the file system.

Comment: can i copy that image to my app data?

Comment: in the `ngFileModel` you are getting the file data in `base64`, so you can do what ever you want with it.